# Aggregate grouped annotation

Tags: django, django-1.9

I'd like to sum all the event durations per day. This is my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

Sample data:

```
import datetime
from random import randint

for i in range(0, 1000):
    start = datetime.datetime(
        year=2016,
        month=1,
        day=randint(1, 10),
        hour=randint(0, 23),
        minute=randint(0, 59),
        second=randint(0, 59)
    )
    end = start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=randint(30, 1000))
    Event.objects.create(start=start, end=end)
```

I can get the event count per day like so:
(I know `extra` is bad, but I'm using 1.9 at the moment. When I upgrade I'll move to using `TruncDate`)

```
Event.objects.extra({'date': 'date(start)'}).order_by('date').values('date').annotate(count=Count('id'))

[{'count': 131, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)},
 {'count': 95, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)},
 {'count': 99, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)},
 {'count': 85, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)},
 {'count': 87, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 5)},
 {'count': 94, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 6)},
 {'count': 97, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 7)},
 {'count': 111, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 8)},
 {'count': 97, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 9)},
 {'count': 104, 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 10)}]
```

I can annotate to add the duration:

```
In [3]: Event.objects.annotate(duration=F('end') - F('start')).first().duration
Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(0, 470)
```

But I can't figure out how to sum this annotation the same way I can count events. I've tried the following but I get a `KeyError` on 'duration'.

```
Event.objects.annotate(duration=F('end') - F('start')).extra({'date': 'date(start)'}).order_by('date').values('date').annotate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))
```

And If I add `duration` to the `values` clause then it no longer groups by date.

Is this possible in a single query and without adding a duration field to the model?

Comment: When you do `values('date')` on that queryset, you eliminate the `duration` field, so there's nothing to sum. What happens if you add 'duration' to the `values()` call and then `order_by('date')` after that? Or, is it necessary to use `values()` at all?

Comment: Hey @ChidG! (how's Ze'ev?) `values` is used for the group_by - I think it's required. If I add `duration` to the `values` call then it tries to group events together by both `date` and `duration`, rather than just by `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to write an answer that Django ORM does not support this. And yes, then I spent another hour on this problem (in addition to the 1,5 hours already spent before starting to write this answer), but as it turns out, Django does support it. And without hacking. Good news!

```
import datetime as dt

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Sum, When, Case
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

from app.models import Event

a = Event.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('start')).values('date').annotate(
    day_duration=Sum(Case(
        When(date=TruncDate(F('start')), then=F('end') - F('start')),
        default=dt.timedelta(), output_field=models.DurationField()
    ))
)
```

And some preliminary tests to (hopefully) prove that this stuff actually does what you asked.

```
In [71]: a = Event.objects.annotate(date=TruncDate('start')).values('date').annotate(day_duration=Sum(Case(
    ...:         When(date=TruncDate(F('start')), then=F('end') - F('start')),
    ...:         default=dt.timedelta(), output_field=models.DurationField()
    ...:     ))
    ...: )

In [72]: for e in a:
    ...:     print(e)
    ...:     
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 41681), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 10)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 46881), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 48650), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 52689), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 8)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 45788), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 5)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 49418), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 7)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 45984), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 9)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 51841), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 63770), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)}
{'day_duration': datetime.timedelta(0, 57205), 'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 6)}

In [73]: q = dt.timedelta()

In [74]: o = Event.objects.filter(start__date=dt.date(2016, 1, 7))

In [75]: p = Event.objects.filter(start__date=dt.date(2016, 1, 10))

In [76]: for e in o:
    ...:     q += (e.end - e.start)

In [77]: q
Out[77]: datetime.timedelta(0, 49418) # Matches 2016.1.7, yay!

In [78]: q = dt.timedelta()

In [79]: for e in p:
    ...:     q += (e.end - e.start)

In [80]: q
Out[80]: datetime.timedelta(0, 41681) # Matches 2016.1.10, yay!
```

NB! This works from version 1.9, I don't think you can do this with the earlier versions because the `TruncDate` function is missing. And before 1.8 you don't have the `Case` and `When` thingies as well of course.

Comment: This is very cool, well done! (Also great to see another djangonaut with a mechatronics background)